# Is this set of continuous functions compact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

I've been trying to wrap my mind around such problems about topology in my free time, this is the problem I can't wrap my mind around.
$$
A = \left\{f(x) = \int_0^1 e^{x + t} g(t)\, dt \,\Big|\;g(x)\in C^0\left([0,1]\right)\right\}  
$$
Is this set compact in $C^0([0,1])$ being the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Topology can be induced by:
$$\text{1.}\, \Vert f \Vert = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx$$
or
$$\rho(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|.$$

Comment: Hint: Can you proove its closed and bounded?

Comment: Hint: what $f$s do we get when choosing $g : t \mapsto \lambda e^{-t}$, with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Hint: we have $A=\{ae^x: a \in \mathbb R\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't compact because in a metric space compactness implies boundedness.
In your case if you compute $|f(0)| \text{, with } g=k\in\mathbb R, $ you get:
$$k\int_0^1 e^t\text dt=k(e-1)\stackrel{k\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} \infty.$$